# Spring boot, пустой ArrayList, хотя ожидаю заполненный

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Создаю бота на spring boot для telegram, есть ArrayList с именем postLinks, ArrayList заполняется элементами в takeAllPosts, это видно по логам, но при запросе размера ArrayList в checker(), размер равен 0. В чем я не прав?

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final String BOT_USERNAME = "BOT_USERNAME";
    private final String BOT_TOKEN = "BOT_TOKEN";
    private final String PARSE_LINK = "https://www.bolha.com/oddaja-stanovanja/maribor";
    private final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";
    private final long MY_ID = MY_ID;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bot.class);
    private ArrayList <String> postLinks = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText() && update.getMessage().getChatId().equals(MY_ID)) {
            if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/start")) {
                sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId(), "Bot stared.");
                takeAllPosts();
                sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId(), "Take " + postLinks.size() + " posts.");//РАЗМЕР НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ
            } else {
                sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId(), "Wrong command.");
            }
        } else {
            sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId(), "Access denied.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return BOT_USERNAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return BOT_TOKEN;
    }

    // Check new post every 10 sec
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000, initialDelay = 5000 * 5)
    public void checker() {
        String link = "";
        try {
            Document page = Jsoup.connect(PARSE_LINK).get();

            Elements linkElements = page.select("h3.entity-title > a");

            link = linkElements.get(3).attr("href");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log.info("size is:" + postLinks.size()); //РАЗМЕР 0, ПОЧЕМУ???

        if (!link.equals(postLinks.get(postLinks.size() - 1))) {
            postLinks.add(link);
            sendPost("https://www.bolha.com".concat(link));
        }

        log.info("link is: " + link);
    }

    private synchronized void sendMsg(Long chatId, String msg) {
        SendMessage helloMessage = new SendMessage();
        helloMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        helloMessage.setText(msg);

        try {
            execute(helloMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void takeAllPosts() {
        int pageNumber = 7;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= pageNumber; i++) {
            try {
                Document page = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bolha.com/oddaja-stanovanja/maribor?page=" + i).get();

                Elements linkElements = page.select("h3.entity-title > a");

                for (int j = (i == 1 ? 2 : 0); j < linkElements.size() - 6; j++) {
                    String link =  linkElements.get(j).attr("href");
                    postLinks.add(link);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(postLinks);
    }
}
```

Comment: на первый взгляд проблема в многопоточности. планировщик всегда выполняет задачу в новом потоке. для того, чтобы это проверить, вместо вашего ArrayList  возьмите  CopyOnWriteArrayList и посмотрите результат.

Comment: @Дмитрий, не помогло, лист всё равно пустой, при обращении к нему из checker()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принял более логичное решение, подключил H2 Database и сохраняю данные в неё, настроил так, что бы database существовала только пока запущен бот, то есть она хранится в оперативной памяти, это решение подходит для небольших баз данных, которые требуются только во время жизни приложения, а при остановке приложения база удаляется.

Comment: Называется In-memory database или IMDB

Comment: @dmtr, да, именно так